# Custom directive inside custom directive doesn't fire

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that loads templates depending on the data, now when I load a template and it happens to have another directive in it, it just simply doesn't render.

I tried pririty, transclude, replace, and any other possible switch but with no success.

Any idea why this works on the root html file but not when inside another directive?

Here is the plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ORF5zXJGFb3Z9Kb0mNyK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because your tile directive creates an isolate scope, meaning any parent scope variables will not be accessible to the tile directive's children. Since the 'basicAreaChart' variable is defined in MainCtrl, it will not be accessible to the template tile2.html

As to how to fix this, you can do it various ways. The simplest would be to abstract the data you need to construct your chart out into a service:

```
app.factory('ChartData', function(){
    return {
        get : function(id){
            return //Your data based on logic
        }
    }
});

app.directive('chart', function(ChartData){
    return {
        //Configuration properties
        scope : {
            chartDataKey : '@'
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attrs){
            var data = ChartData.get(scope.chartDataKey);
            //More logic
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Clark but the use of a service is a bit unclear, can you edit the plunker and show me? the idea here is to have a single JSON when the page loads that has everything, including url for templates and all the data each tile is going to use so if I start passing data to a service so the other directive can catch it, it may seem a bit unpractical and will escalability.

Comment: You're right this solution would not be as reusable... Let me think on it a bit.